# Ruby 2.4.x Net::FTP: How to set the implicite FTPS mode?

Tags: ruby, ftps

I'm upgrading a Rails app and I changed the Ruby version to 2.4.5 which makes the `double-bag-ftps` gem no more compatible as [it is stated in this issue](https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps/issues/17).

In this issue, there is an exemple of a pure Ruby version, but I'm missing the way to set the FTPS mode (implicit or explicit).

I can't find anything about it in [the Ruby's doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.5/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) so I'm hopping someone here knows about it.

Anyone knows how to handle this with the pure Ruby `Net::FTP` class?

Or should it be done manually ?

Comment: The comment by jnimety on that issue shows how to do it by overriding the `connect` method on the `Net::FTP` class. Why not compare his version to the built-in `connect` and see what was changed?

Comment: Yep, I used it and it's working. Thank you